# Cannot import hamcrest matchers for some reason

Tags: hamcrest

I am super new to unit testing and java in general, so my apologies for the basic question. However, when I try to import import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasEntry; I get a message saying "cannot resolve symbol 'Matchers'. I'm trying to use hasEntry to unit test a method that returns a map.

Here are the imports I have

```
    import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
    import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
    import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasEntry;
```

the top two are working fine, but I can't get the last one to work. If anyone has any suggestions as to how to fix the problem, or if there is another way I can import hasEntry, please let me know! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Hamcrest are you using?
It would be great if you put your pom.xml file here to facilitate the analysis.
Maybe you only need to trigger another import maven command (with force update snapshots) in your IDE, for example, to refresh your local dependencies.
Or you can try this:

```
mvn --batch-mode --update-snapshots clean package
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Hamcrest prior to version 2.x and are missing the `hamcrest-library.jar` that provides `org.hamcrest.Matchers`.

If you are using Junit4, then `hamcrest-core.jar` is already included as dependency, which is why the `org.hamcrest.CoreMatcher` can be imported.

From the [Documentation about Hamcrest distributables](https://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/distributables):

> Prior to version 2.x, Hamcrest was distributed through multiple jars [...]
>
> From Hamcrest version 2.x, all the classes in hamcrest-core.jar were moved into hamcrest.jar.